# Why is ValueError thrown by keras.models.model_from_config() in the Keras-to-Tensorflow exporting example?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

The Keras website has [this article](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html#exporting-a-model-with-tensorflow-serving) about exporting Keras models to core Tensorflow. However the step

```
new_model = model_from_config(config)
```

throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hal9000/tf_serving_experiments/sndbx.py", line 38, in <module>
    new_model = model_from_config(config)
  File "/home/hal9000/keras2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 304, in model_from_config
    return layer_module.deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/hal9000/keras2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 54, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/hal9000/keras2env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 122, in deserialize_keras_object
    raise ValueError('Improper config format: ' + str(config))
ValueError: Improper config format: {'layers': [{'class_name': 'InputLayer', 'config': {...
```

People have suggested that there's a problem using the `model_from_config()` method with Keras v1 models since the release of v2. However I have tried this with a range of models from different versions, including the built-in Keras `ResNet50` and a simple single-layer MLP defined in that very script. All throw the same error.

It would appear that the `keras.utils.generic_utils.deserialize_keras_object()` method wants to find a key `"class_name"` or `"config"` in the `config` dictionary ([see source](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/generic_utils.py#L121)). Upon inspection of the `config` dict that `get_config()` creates, there is no such entry; instead there are keys:

- `"input_layers"`
- `"layers"`
- `"name"`
- `"output_layers"`

I also opened an issue https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/7232 and created a Gist that you can run for yourself and see the error. https://gist.github.com/9thDimension/e1cdb2cd11f11309bfaf297b276f7456

- Keras 2.0.6
- Tensorflow 1.1.0

Answer (score 4):

For whatever reason the dictionry object that `keras.models.Model.get_config()` returns is not compatible with the `keras.models.model_from_config()` method to rehydrate models.

I replaced these with equivalent calls to `keras.models.Model.model_to_json()` and `keras.models.model_from_json()` and was able to proceed successfully.

Answer (score 4):

The inverse of `keras.models.Model.get_config()` seems to be `keras.models.Model.from_config()`, not `keras.models.model_from_config()` https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/. Try that instead?