# Is there a way to activate dropout during inference in Keras, while freezing batch norm layers

Tags: keras, deep-learning, uncertainty

I am trying to use the dropout layers in my model ***during inference time*** to measure the model uncertainty 
as described in [the method outlined by Yurin Gal](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/yarin/blog_3d801aa532c1ce.html)

A solution is described in this post:
[How to calculate prediction uncertainty using Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529931/how-to-calculate-prediction-uncertainty-using-keras), which defines a new Keras function
 `self.f = K.function([self.graph.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()], [self.graph.layers[-1].output])`

However, this method does not hold if the used model has batch normalisation layers. As this will make the model not use the mean and variance learned during training, but set new ones depending on the current batch.

Hence, I am looking for a way to put the batch layers training parameter to false but keep the dropout layer in training mode?

I am using the Keras efficientNet B0 as model, trained on custom data [keras_efficientNet](https://github.com/titu1994/keras-efficientnets)

I already tried to change the layers settings myself

```
`
        for layer in self.graph.layers[4].layers:
            if 'batch_norm' in layer.name:
                layer._trainable = False
                layer._inbound_nodes[0].output_tensors[0]._uses_learning_phase = False
                layer._inbound_nodes[0].input_tensors[0]._uses_learning_phase = False
            if 'dropout' in layer.name:
                layer._inbound_nodes[0].output_tensors[0]._uses_learning_phase = True
            for weight in self.graph.layers[4].weights:
                if 'batch_norm' in weight.name:
                    weight._trainable = False`
```

Nonetheless, none of this worked.

Answer (score 0):

This question is duplicated, it is already answered here [How to apply Monte Carlo Dropout, in tensorflow, for an LSTM if batch normalization is part of the model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031302/how-to-apply-monte-carlo-dropout-in-tensorflow-for-an-lstm-if-batch-normalizat/62032206#62032206)

Basically, when you define your model, you should add `training=True` to your Dropout layer

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(...) 
x = tf.keras.layers.___(...)(input)
...
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(...)(x, training=True)
...
```

In the case, you cannot modify the model constructor code, you can modify it like this
(*not my favourite solution*) [[1]](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4450#issuecomment-409071170).

```
# load model
model_config = model.get_config()
layer_index = 3 # layer index you want to modify
model_config['layers'][layer_index]['inbound_nodes'][0][0][-1]['training'] = True
model = tf.keras.models.model_from_config(model_config)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. 
the issue is that I am not defining the model again. I am only using it for inference and don't want to train it again.I use the load function from keras.model to load the already trained .h5 model. is there a way to change the definition of the model when loading it this way?

Answer (score 0):

thank you @pedrolarben for your solution, it helped me a lot but was incomplete!

what finally worked was the following

1. `model_config = self.graph.get_config()`
2. **you need to change the inbound_nodes of the config of the layer not the inbound_nodes directly**
   `model_config['layers'][layer_index]['config']['layers'][index_of_dropout_layer]['inbound_nodes'][0][0][-1]['training'] = True`
3. reload the model: (as stated in this answer [The inverse of keras.models.Model.get_config() seems to be keras.models.Model.from_config(), not keras.models.model_from_config()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51244126/9568715)):

`model = Model.from_config(model_config)`

4. And finally you need to load the weights again, otherwise your model is randomly initialized `model.load_weights(self.graph_path)`

**Note**: this works for the keras implementation of efficientNet.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#privileged_training_argument_in_the_call_method) to create custom layer, also there is an example using custom dropout Layer, so that you can manipulate training values during training also inference time **to make dropout running on inference time**

```
class CustomDropout(keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, rate, **kwargs):
    super(CustomDropout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.rate = rate

def call(self, inputs, training=None):
    if training: #you can remove this line,, so that you can use dropout on inference time
        return tf.nn.dropout(inputs, rate=self.rate)
    return inputs
```