Activate Monte Carlo Dropout of a given Keras model for evaluation
I use hyperparameter optimization to determine the best hyperparameters of my model. Then I generate a new model and train it with dropout layers. After that I test the performance using test data.
I also want to test the uncertainty of this model. Therefore, I want to implement Monte Carlo dropout. When I generate a new model, I can tell the model that the dropout layers should also be activated during the evaluation:
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(...)(x, training=True)
However, I then do not get an evaluation of the model without Monte Carlo Dropout. But I would like to have both:

the evaluation without Monte Carlo dropout and
the evaluation with Monte Carlo dropout (e.g. the variance over 50 evaluations)

I did some googling and found a solution to set a model whose dropout layers were initialized without training=True to training=True:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342783/is-there-a-way-to-activate-dropout-during-inference-in-keras-while-freezing-bat
Based on this, my code looks like this:
layerName = []
for count in range(len(model.layers)):
    layer = model.layers[count]
    layerName.append(layer.__class__.__name__)
model_config = model.get_config()
for count in range(len(model.layers)):
    if "Dropout" in layerName[count]:
        model_config['layers'][count+1]['config']["trainable"] = True   
modelDropout = model.from_config(model_config)
modelDropout.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=...), loss=...)

However, when I run multiple predictions, I always get the same loss, so something seems to be wrong. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Or do you know another solution to my problem?
